# Which Analyzer to get results of appended words when data has space or dash in between?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

my mapping looks like as below. As you can see that Name field is analyzed

```
     {
       "state":"open",
       "settings":{
          "index":{
             "creation_date":"1453816191454",
             "number_of_shards":"5",
             "number_of_replicas":"1",
             "version":{
                "created":"1070199"
             },           
          }
       },
       "mappings":{
          "Product":{
             "properties":{
                "index":"not_analyzed",
                "store":true,
                "type":"string"
             },
            "Name":{                  
                "store":true,
                "type":"string"
             },            
             "Number":{
                "index":"not_analyzed",
                "store":true,
                "type":"string"
             },
             "id":{
                "index":"no",
                "store":true,
                "type":"integer"
   }
         }
      },
      "aliases":[

      ]
   }
}
```

When I query as below

```
   "query": {
            "match_phrase": {
               "Name": "hl-2240"
            }
         }
```

This works fine and also "hl 2240" works fine but when I type "hl2240". I dont get any results. I understand that it is because name is indexed as "hl-2240" and I guess that I am using standart or generic analyzer and it tokenizes as hl and 2240. while I dont have any token as hl2240 in reverse index, It doesnt find anything. I learnt that I should use another analyzer. But this is where I am stuck at. Which analyzer I can use? Should I reindex my index or I can use the Analyzer only to query? If I change the analyzer to index my data, I want to make sure that I am not loosing results for searching "hl-2240" or "hl 2240".

Update: Nest query I tried for Richa's answer.

```
   Client.CreateIndex("myIndex",
            ci => ci.Analysis(a => a.TokenFilters(f => f.Add("my_word_delimiter", new WordDelimiterTokenFilter
            {
              CatenateAll = true          

            }))
            .Analyzers(an => an.Add("my_analyzer", new CustomAnalyzer
            {
              Tokenizer = "whitespace",
              Filter = new List<string> {"standard",
              "lowercase",
              "my_word_delimiter"}
            }))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this `analyzer`:

```
{
 "settings": {
  "analysis": {
       "filter": {
        "my_word_delimiter": {
           "type": "word_delimiter",
           "catenate_all": true     <=== Notice this

        }
     },
     "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "whitespace",
           "filter": [
              "standard",
              "lowercase",
              "my_word_delimiter"
           ]
        }
     }

    }
  }
}
```

Read about [catenate_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html).

Use following command to see how string is being tokenized:

```
 curl -XGET "localhost:9200/index_8/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty=true" -d 'hl-2240'
```

THis will produce following output and `hl-2240` will be indexed as

```
{
"tokens" : [ {
 "token" : "hl",
"start_offset" : 0,
"end_offset" : 2,
"type" : "word",
"position" : 0
}, {
"token" : "hl2240",
"start_offset" : 0,
"end_offset" : 7,
"type" : "word",
"position" : 0
}, {
"token" : "2240",
"start_offset" : 3,
"end_offset" : 7,
"type" : "word",
"position" : 1
 }  ]
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I tried to write it with Nest. Can you please see my updated question? does it look correct? I am not sure how to add "catenate_all" in settings.

Comment: Sry, I am not familiar with nest??

Comment: this is how the index looks like in the Metadata. Is it how it supposed to look like? Am I not supposed to see anything about  "standard",
              "lowercase" filters?

{
"state": "open",
"settings": {
"index": {
"creation_date": "1456931106473",
"analysis": {
"filter": {
"my_word_delimiter": {
"catenate_all": "true",
"type": "word_delimiter"
}
},
"my_analyzer": {
"type": "custom"
},
"analyzer": "my_analyzer"
},
"number_of_shards": "5",
"number_of_replicas": "1",
"uuid": "_EGJHKKHPM",
"version": {
"created": "2020099"
}
}
},

Comment: Produced result for hl-2240 is as you mentioned

Comment: when I query, i cant get the result with a simple match query. Do I have to adjust something in the query as well? {"index":"my_Index","type":"Product"}
{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"type":"best_fields","query":"hl2240","fields":["Number^8","Name^7"]}}]}}}

Comment: Above query  seems fine. :)

Comment: just In addition to your query, I should have added analyzer in my mapping of the field as well

"Name": {
  "store": true,
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "search_analyzer": "standard"
}